# How to rotate an arc using trigonomentry p5js?

Tags: p5.js

I want to create a spinning arc using trig, nothing fancy, just for it to rotate around the center point as if it was a full rotating circle cut in half. What I'm doing now results in a funky pacman, whereas I want it to remain a semicircle.

```js
let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  let posX = 250;
  let posY = 250;
  let sizeW = 250;
  let sizeH = 250; 
  let radius = 125 //I don't know what to put as my radius
  let x = radius * cos(angle);
  let y = radius * sin(angle);

  
  fill(0);
  arc(posX, posY , sizeW, sizeH, 270 + x, 90 + y);
 
  angle++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any trigonometry because the `arc()` function takes care of that for you. You just need to make the start and end angles for the arc change based on the current value of `angle`. To get a semi-circle shape you want to start the arc ~90 degrees clockwise from `angle` and end your arc ~90 degrees counter clockwise from `angle`.

```js
const posX = 250;
const posY = 250;
const sizeW = 250;
const sizeH = 250; 
const radius = 125;

let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);

  fill(0);
  arc(posX, posY , sizeW, sizeH, angle + 90, angle - 90);
 
  angle++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```